# Using cot(x) in C

Tags: c

I have a code below to calculate area and perimeter of a heptagon. The formula for it, area = (1/4)nk2 cot(π/n). As far as I know we can't use "cot" in C and according to my google searches, we should be using like 1/tan(x). But it's not working. Can anyone help and explain how to do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//Area and Perimeter of a Heptagon
//Area = (1/4) * 7 * (edge * edge) * cot(pi / 7)
//Perimeter = edge * 7

float pi = 3.141592;

float area;
float perimeter;
float edge;

printf("Enter one edge of your Heptagon: ");
scanf("%f", &edge);
printf("Edge = %f\n", edge);

area = (1/4) * 7 * (edge * edge) * 1/tan(pi / 7);
perimeter = edge * 7;

printf("Area = %f\n", area);
printf("Perimeter = %f\n", perimeter);


system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `1/4` is integer division... is `0`. Try `1.0/4.0` (or `0.25`) and prefer `double` rather than `float`.

Comment: @pmg `.25` :) .....

Comment: any reason of using floats instead of double

Comment: ..and when you do, a more accurate library value of *pi* is available (`M_PI` with MS Visual C).

Comment: I'm using float because I've seen it in C lessons on the internet. What's the difference in here exactly?

Comment: The difference is 20th century teaching. It hasn't caught up with the technology. Never use `float` unless you have a very good reason to. The technical difference is that `double` is bigger and better - more accurate.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @WeatherVane: TBH using `double` is early 21st century teaching. All the AI folks are thinking that `float` is already on the big side. Bigger is worse, unless you need the accuracy :)

Comment: @MSalters that would be in the category "a good reason not to?" C compilers think `1.2345` is of type `double` and is the default for type promotions for variadic functions.

Comment: @MSalters: the AI folks use [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) perhaps? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1/4` is integer division, so this will give you 0. Even if some or all of the subsequent factors cause a promotion to float, the result will still be zero.

Use something like `1.0f / 4.0f` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is small logical error in your program , everytime you write an expression in C all the variables or constants are converted into a same type , now when your are dividing 1 and 4 the compiler understands them both as integers and it calculates it and yields the final expression in integer only due to type conversion carried on by default . So 1/4 will be yielding an value 0 which will be multiplied in the rest of expression , finally resulting a final answer as 0 .
So i would suggest you to use the expression

**area = (1.00 / 4.00) * 7.00 * (edge * edge) * (1.00 / tan(pi / 7));**

to remove any of the type conversion errors .

Answer (score 1):

Consider the several types and implicit conversions:

```
float pi = 3.141592;
float area;
float edge;
area = (1/4) * 7 * (edge * edge) * 1/tan(pi / 7);
```

`float pi = 3.141592` is `float pi = (float) (double) 3.141592`. (implicit conversion)

`1/4` is an `int/int`: quotient is `(int) 0`.  (OP's main problem)

`(int) 0 * 7` is `int * int`: product is `(int) 0`.

`edge * edge` is `float * float`: product is `(float) e`.

`(int) 0 * (float) e`  is `(float) 0 * (float) e`: product is `(float) 0`.

`(float) 0 * 1`  is `(float) 0 * (float) (int)1`: product is `(float) 0`.  (implicit conversion)

`pi / 7` is `float / (float) (int)7`: quotient is `(float) f`.  (implicit conversion)

`tan(f)` is `tan((double) f)`: result if `(double) g`.  (implicit conversion)

`(float) 0 / (double) g` is `(double) (float) 0 / (double) g`: quotient is `(double) 0`.  (implicit conversion)

`area = (double) 0` is `area = (float)(double) 0`.  (implicit conversion)

I count **6** implicit conversions + 2 more in the `printf()`.  Best to have none.

```
float pi = 3.141592f;
area = (1.0f/4.0f) * 7.0f * (edge * edge) * 1.0f/tanf(pi / 7.0f);
```

Even better.  Little reason to use `float` as `double` is the default *floating point* type for C - and let the system provide the best machine π.

```
const double pi = acos(-1.0);
double area = (1.0/4.0) * 7.0 * (edge * edge) * 1.0/tan(pi / 7.0);
printf("Area = %f\n", area);
```